# Error while installing google chrome in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: google-chrome, dependencies

I just installed ubuntu 14.10. When I tried to install `google_chrome_stable.deb` from software center, it shows following error.

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libappindicator1
```

Comment: Please post the error messages you got into your post, then try this `sudo apt -f install` and try again.

Comment: ... and please notice that 14.10 has passed end of life and will receive no security updates. It is better to upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu, for example 16.04.1 LTS. (It is also possible to install 14.04.1 LTS or 14.04.5 LTS).

Answer (score 1):

To install Google Chrome, type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

Instead of `google-chrome-stable` you can choose from either `google-chrome-beta` or `google-chrome-unstable` packages if you want.

**If you get new errors** after running `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb`, run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

That will resolve broken dependencies. During the installation a PPA is added to your system so that Google Chrome receives the latest updates whenever you check for system updates with `sudo apt-get update`.